# Plotlyjs Treemap chart is not rendering

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I am trying to create Treemap chart using below link

[Plotly Treemap](https://plotly.com/javascript/treemaps/)

Now I am trying to generate Treemap which shows revenue for same companies in different years

index.js:

```
    data = [{
      type: "treemap",
      labels: ["company 1","company 2","company 3","company 1","company 2","company 3"],
      parents: ["2017","2017","2017","2018","2018","2018"],
      values: [15,20,30,23,45,56]
   }]

   Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data)
```

Index.html

```
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.1.0.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

But it is not rendering any chart. Please suggest if i am making any mistake in constructing data

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to do 3D data, when a treemap is 2d: a hierarchy and optional values.

First, *labels* must be unique, these are the nodes in the tree.

Second, *parents* describe the parent node, from *labels* at the same offset.  Use the parent name "" to describe the root node.

Your values are fine.  Try changing you data to (you see you lose the years):

```
var data = [{
      type: "treemap",
      labels: ["company 1","company 2","company 3","company 4","company 5","company 6"],
      parents: ["","company 1","company 1","company 2","company 3","company 1"],
      values: [15,20,30,23,45,56]
   }];
```

CodePen example: [Ploty treemap](https://codepen.io/slipping-jimmy/pen/MWoMKyJ)